# How to call jquery lightBox from loaded content

Tags: jquery, image, load, loaded

I'm trying to use jquery lightbox to display photos that are loaded into a page using load(). My code is:

```
$('#content').on('click', 'a.thumb_link', function(){        
    $('a.thumb_link').lightBox();
    return false;
});
```

This works only if I click the link twice.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted to suggest two clicks are needed. Please set up a JS Fiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Are you using [Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)? Or which plugin?

Comment: 2 clicks, one click function, makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm baffled, why the 2 provided answers didn't work?

At the end, I managed to get it working by including my JS inside the loaded page, so that the script was loaded into the page along with the other content.

This did the trick:

```
$('a.thumb_link').lightBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like

```
$('#content').live('click', function()
{
   $('a.thumb_link').lightBox();
   return false;
}
```

If I had more code as an example to work with I might be able to provide a better solution but I can only grab at straws assuming what content is, to the link with the class `thumb_link`

Comment: one you have to encapsulate the code you place in comments in back ticks the key to the left of the one under the escape key (on US keyboards at least). 2, you could "edit" your original post to add additional feedback in a scenario like this so its easier to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete code:

loaded.php

```
<a class="thumb_link" href="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-1.jpg">
<img src="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-1.jpg"></a>

<a class="thumb_link" href="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-3.jpg">
<img src="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-3.jpg"></a>
```

test.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"        media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>

<body>
<a class="link" href="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-1.jpg">
<img src="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-1.jpg">
</a>

<a class="link" href="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-3.jpg">
<img src="../members/21000_21999/21659/21659-3.jpg">
</a>

<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.link').lightBox();

    $('#content').load('loaded.php');

    $('#content').on('click', 'a.thumb_link', function(){        
        $('a.thumb_link').lightBox();
        return false;
    }); 


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The top 2 images which are coded directly in test.php will run lightBox with a single click on the image. The bottom 2 loaded images only run lightBox when I click them twice.

Or, the loaded images will run lightBox if I first click a top image and then click the loaded image (still two clicks)

Im using:
jquery v1.7.1
jquery lightBox v0.5